# Outlier detection in data generated from multiple units

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, outliers

Imagine the following scenario -- I have access to a set $M$ of $k$ machines (or units), with machine $m_i$ generating $x_{it}$ pieces of a product in time-period $t$. $X$ is a random variable, and is affected by a set of covariates $w$. While the aggregated data generated by all the machine is not i.i.d, I assume that all dependencies and machine-specific information is modeled in the feature-space. Using all the aggregated data, I learn a distribution over the number of products produced in a time period, conditional on $w$. Let's call this $f(X \mid w)$. For example, this could be a Poisson distribution.

Now, my goal is to identify which machines are outliers, or are not performing on par with other machines. This is tricky, as individual realizations of $X$ are affected by the covariates. For example, may be a machine produced less products in a time-period since it was extremely hot that day, causing the system to over-heat. One way I can think of is to sum the probability mass for all realizations from a machine, and construct a distribution for the resulting quantity. Let's denote to this quantity by $y$, such that $y_k = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^{T}f(x_{kt}|w_{kt})}{T}$, where $T$ is the total number of time periods, and $w_{kt}$ is the set of covariates for machine $m_k$ at time $t$. My questions are --

a) How can I then pick outliers from $Y$?

b) For any arbitrary distribution over $X$, how can I find the distribution of $Y$?

c) Is there a standard procedure for dealing with this problem?

I would appreciate being referred to sources where I can study more on this.